# How can I set an option in testthat before my package is loaded?

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I am writing unit tests for a package using testthat.

The package maintains a cache of database connections, which are configured with YAML files. The cache is populated during loading by searching for config files in specific paths, including `rappdirs::site_config_dir()` and `rappdirs::user_config_dir()`.

This behaviour is desired in normal usage but during testing it means the tests will not be reproducible on different machines and over time.

My current approach is to create a `configure`/`don't configure` switch based on a global option in `.onLoad()`:

```r
    no_connect <- options("SQLHELPER_NO_CONNECT_ON_LOAD")

    if(is.null(no_connect[[1]])){
      create_connections()

    } else if(no_connect[[1]] == FALSE) { 
      create_connections()
    }
```

which works interactively; my question is:

How can I make `testthat` set the option *before it loads the package*?

(I have tried fiddling with `tests/testthat.R`, but it is [not recommended](https://r-pkgs.org/testing-basics.html#initial-setup) and only used in `R CMD check` anyway. I'm hoping for something that also works with `devtools::test()` etc)

**UPDATE** I thought briefly that I could set the option in `tests/testthat/setup.R`, but I think I must have got confused after playing with setting and unsetting it for an afternoon. For anyone reading this in search of an answer, `setup.R` is run by `testthat` *after* `.onLoad()`is run by loading the package.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @LorenzoG see Hadley Wickham's suggestion here: https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/1702